# JDBC Oracle from within Docker Container: Connection Refused

Tags: oracle, docker, jdbc

I am attempting to Dockerize a Spring MVC application, but cannot connect to my Oracle database from within the container.  The application uses connection pooling.  I get the following error when using `ojdbc6_g.jar`:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    ...
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM tomcat:9
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=MST
ADD target/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

The Spring Bean looks like this:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" name="ds">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:jack/sparrow@HOST:PORT/service" />
</bean>
```

Interestingly, if I change the username/password to something I know is incorrect, then the error changes from "Connection refused" to what I would expect: "Invalid credentials".  I am using SpringMVC: 4.1.1 with JdbcTemplate.  In an attempt to isolate the problem, I tried the following simplified code:

```
import java.sql.*;

class TestOJDBC {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:EXACT_SAME_CONNECT_STRING");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    s.execute("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
    s.getResultSet().next();
    int i = s.getResultSet().getInt(1);
    System.out.println("The integer received was: " + i);
  }
}
```

With this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:9
ADD ojdbc6.jar /usr/src/
ADD TestOJDBC.java /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/
RUN javac TestOJDBC.java
CMD ["java", "-classpath", ".:/usr/src/ojdbc6.jar", "TestOJDBC"]
```

Interestingly, this minimal example succeeds in connecting to the Database!

Does anybody have any debugging tips for me as I Dockerize my Oracle/SpringMVC application?

Comment: New development: I downloaded tomcat 7, 8, and 9 to my computer, and try running the application directly from the system (without containers), and am getting the same error.

Comment: Connection refused errors are normally specific to receiving a TCP RESET in response to the initial SYN request opening a TCP connection. It's unlikely you would get one for the same connection after successful auth, maybe there are new connections created for a pool? or to a cluster? or oracle uses some fancy connection handoff after auth?

Comment: Given that your `TestOJDBC` class connects but Tomcat doesn't, I'm going to guess that SELinux (or similar) is involved.  Is it?  What OS are you using?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I am using Ubuntu 17 (Host OS).

Comment: It must be some other setup within the project that is messing everything up: I created a minimal servlet that makes the same JDBC connection within Tomcat (within Docker nonetheless), and everything works; I am going to further research if the connection pooler I am using is doing something funky